# Randomize insertion in for-loop

Tags: javascript

I'd like to randomize my HTML-output with multiple elements within my for-loop:

```
var h = document.getElementById("test_block");
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  h.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div class='one_hour onesy'><p>Foo</p></div>");
}
```

With a random output within the forloop of:

```
<div class='one_hour onesy'><p>Foo</p></div>
<div class='two_hour onesy'><p>Loo</p></div>
<div class='three_hour onesy'><p>Too</p></div>
```

So I'd like to get the adjacented HTML to be randomly one of these lines.
How can I do that?

Comment: what is shower_total, where you define it? where do you you use i?

Comment: Sorry shower_total is a calculation that has nothing to do with the thing here. It is "7"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see if this helps:

```
var results = [
  '<div class="one_hour onesy"><p>Foo</p></div>',
  '<div class="two_hour onesy"><p>Foo</p></div>',
  'whatever',
  ...
];

for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  h.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", results[Math.floor((Math.random() * results.length))]);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to `Math.floor()` this rather than round, as there's no value in `results[results.length]`